# PDE in S.-T. Yau College Student Mathematics Contests 2019

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

This problem is from S.-T. Yau College Student Mathematics Contests 2019.
I don't have enough pre-knowledge, but I want to learn.

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a bounded domain with smooth
boundary. Prove that, for all $p>1$ and $1\leq q<\infty$, for all
$f\in L^p(\Omega)$, there exists a unique $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$, such
that
$$\Delta u = |u|^{q-1} u+f  \  \text{in} \ \Omega.$$

Comment: If $q=1$, don't we need a boundary condition to have a unique $u$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog There should be a boudary condition in the definition of $H^1_0(\Omega)$. $H^1_0(\Omega)$ is the completion space of $C^1_0(\Omega)$.($C^1_0(\Omega)$=$\left\{u\in C^1(\overline{\Omega})|u(x)=0,{\rm{when}}\ x\ {\rm is\ a\ member\ of\ some\ neighborhood\ of\ }\partial\Omega\right\}$)

Comment: I don't know what is expected knowledge for these kinds of competitions, but my immediate thought was that this could be done using the mountain pass theorem

Comment: Have a look at section 8.5.2 in Partial Differential Equations by Evans - there's an extremely similar example to the question you have, but it needs to be adapted to prove the case $n=2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- For the existence, note that the corresponding functional:
  \begin{align}
  E(u)&=\int \frac{1}{2}|\nabla u|s^2 + \frac{1}{q+1}|u|^{q+1}+fu\\
  &\geq \int\frac{1}{2} |\nabla u|^2 +\frac{1}{q+1}|u|^{q+1}-\epsilon \|u\|_{L^{p'}} -C(\epsilon)\|f\|_{L^p}.
  \end{align}
  The Sobolev embedding yields that $E$ is bounded from below, then the direct method in variational methods (see, for instance, Variational Methods-Michael Struwe, Theorem 1.2) yields that the problem admits a solution.
- For the uniqueness, if $u_1, u_2$ are two solutions, then we have
  $$\Delta u_{1}-\Delta u_{2}=|u_{1}|^{p-1}u_{1}-|u_{2}|^{p-1}u_{2},$$
  multiplying it by $u_{1}-u_{2}$ and intergral by parts, we obtain
  $$\int |\nabla (u_{1}-u_{2})|^2+ (|u_{1}|^{p-1}u_{1}-|u_{2}|^{p-1}u_{2})(u_{1}-u_{2})=0.$$
  If $u_{1}>u_{2}$, $(|u_{1}|^{p-1}u_{1}-|u_{2}|^{p-1}u_{2})(u_{1}-u_{2})>0,$
  otherwise, $u_{1}\leq u_{2}$, we still have  $$(|u_{1}|^{p-1}u_{1}-|u_{2}|^{p-1}u_{2})(u_{1}-u_{2})\geq 0,$$
  which means that $u_{1}=u_{2}.$
- I must point out that, the mountain pass theorem is used to deal with the problem
  $$-\Delta u= |u|^{q-1}u+f,$$
  which is totally different, since it admits infinitely many solutions by papers of Rabinowitz. And the problem is similar to Variational Methods-Michael Struwe, Theorem 1.3.

Comment: Yasuo bro, I want to know if you play QQ, thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Ah yes, I completely missed that there wasn't the minus sign in front of the Laplacian. Great solution (+1)

Comment: So the theorem says we should put $\frac{1}{2}$ in front of $|\nabla u|^2$.

Comment: Yes, I forgot the $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Should we put a $\frac{1}{q+1}$ in front of $|u|^{q+1}$